# Interesting function

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I asked this question on MO but haven't received any answers, so I thought I'd try here. Denote by $L^1(0,1)$ the space of Lebesgue integrable functions on the interval $(0,1)$.

**Question:** Does there exist a function $F:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $\frac{F(x)}{x}\in L^1(0,1)$,
2. $\frac{F'(x)}{x}\in L^1(0,1)$,
3. $\frac{F(x)}{x^2}\notin L^1(0,1)$?

My guess is that the answer is yes and the point is to construct $F$ such that $F$ and $F'$ behave suitably near zero. It seems quite delicate. I checked that $F$ cannot be a polynomial or a power function (since then $F'\simeq \frac{F}x$, thus conditions 2 and 3 cannot hold simultaneously).

I would appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such $F$ exists. From 2. we obtain that
$$F(x) = \int_0^x t\cdot g(t)\,dt$$
for some $g \in L^1(0,1)$ (perhaps with additional regularity if e.g. $F$ should be continuously differentiable rather than merely absolutely continuous). A nonzero integration constant would violate 1. Since
$$\lvert F(x)\rvert \leqslant x \int_0^x \lvert g(t)\rvert\,dt$$
the function $x \mapsto F(x)/x$ is bounded (and continuous), hence belongs to $L^1(0,1)$.

By Tonelli's theorem we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\lvert F(x)\rvert}{x^2}\,dx
&\leqslant \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x t\cdot \lvert g(t)\rvert\,dt\,dx \\
&= \int_0^1 t\cdot \lvert g(t)\rvert \int_t^1 \frac{dx}{x^2}\,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 t\cdot\lvert g(t)\rvert \biggl(\frac{1}{t} - 1\biggr)\,dt \\
&\leqslant \int_0^1 \lvert g(t)\rvert\,dt + \int_0^1 t\cdot \lvert g(t)\rvert\,dt \\
&< +\infty\,,
\end{align}
hence also $\frac{F(x)}{x^2} \in L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: Great, thank you!